# Chord function of "NOW AND FOREVER"

Tags: chord-progressions

Hi everyone I have a question about chord function again it is "Now and forever" song by Richard Marx as the picture below[image]

I don't understand the function of C#m7b5 and second line that start by C chord, is that the  key changed?

I appreciate in advance for every knowledge you give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C#m7b5 is the 7 chord based on the 7th note of the scale D major. 
It has a dominant function. In this case the key is G. So I would say the it functions as a secondary dominant or the dominant of the dominant.

However it is most likely there as a passing chord.

Comment: I don't see how you can call this a passing chord as they lean on it for so long (although I agree that functionally it's acting as a bV/I, but instead of going directly to one, the song goes to a ii-V-I.

Comment: I played it to see on guitar. I don't know how long it is on for in the actual performance thou. I just assumed the first few syllables were said in passing. Also If the Am7 is played in first inversion the the bass line goes D C# C. So it just feels to me like they passed through it on the way to Am7.

Comment: I did the same thing.  Clearly the only reason for the choice of the C#7b5 is to continue the bass line (E-D-C#).  The resolution is delayed as instead of going to G it goes to the ii-V-I, but they do kinda hint at a key change to Bmi.  I don't think the composer was really thinking in terms of any kind of rules.

Comment: The song sits on the C#mi7b5 and it's a nice sound.

Comment: I agree with you. I figure the composer was aiming for a nice sound more than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

For my opinion by ear, I feel C#m7b5 can be resolved by G. 
Am Dsus D in next line just delay to G, I feel like this.